# itunesconnect ios app release at specified date and time

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, autorelease

I have v1.x.y of my iOS app on the App Store already "Ready For Sale".
And v2.0.0 of the app uploaded and approved by Apple, with the status now showing as "Pending Developer Release".

I intend to release the app to the users (public) at a specific date and time.
I set the release note message and date-time for release, and click the "Save" button on top right.
[image]
After that, i see this page.
[image]
Should i also click the "**Release This Version**" button on top right?

i read the [***documentation here***](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html), but it doesn't clearly state or illustrate, so I'm confused about the correct complete procedure.

Comment: Don't click it. It will be released on April 5.

Answer (score 0):

when you set automatically release date and time to app is release that specific date and time, if your app status is ready to sale. otherwise app not release..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule  the time when u want release so go for time period or else you want to release immediately go with release this version.